# Qmake и Rebuild all

Tags: qtcreator, qmake

Объясните пожалуйста, как работают эти кнопки в Qtcreator'e.

Прочитал в нескольких гайдах, что qmake выполняет pro файлы. Это файлы, в которых описано, как собирать проект в рабочую программу (грубо говоря). Про Rebuild all вообще нигде не видел инфы.

Много раз тестил у себя на компе, и выяснил, что Rebuild All выполняет всё, что написано в pro файлах, кроме функций. А qmake выполняет только функции. Я правильно всё понял или это зависит от каких-то настроек? Можно ли настроить так, чтобы выполнять оба действия одной кнопкой?

Что точно делает каждая из кнопок? В интернете информация об этом размытая, такая, как будто это все знают, и оно само собой разумеется.

Пример:
В проекте есть файл iss_generator.pri. Он подключен в pro файл следующим образом.

```
include(iss_generator.pri)
```

Вот код этого файла.

```
iss_file = $$DeployDir/install.iss

iss ="Здесь большой текст этого файла"

write_file($$iss_file, iss)
```

Файл появляется в папке только при qmake. При build не появляется.

Comment: `qmake` парсит файл проекта и генерирует `Makefile`. `rebuild all` использует результат его работы и заменяет последовательность двух команд `clean => build`

Comment: Значит qmake генерирует Makefile на основе pro файлов. Тогда почему Build выполняет копирование всех файлов куда надо, но не выполняет функции, написанные в этих pro файлах?

Comment: В то же время в таком случае qmake не должен сам выполнять эти функции, а только генерировать Makefile. А он их выполняет.

Comment: О каких функциях идёт речь? Добавьте пример в вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо. Добавил.

Comment: Спасибо за форматирование, у меня с телефона не видно такой функции.

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужно создать  [custom target](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets). Я этой фунциональностью `qmake` не пользовался - просто знаю о возможности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Система сборки, основанная на `qmake` - двухфазная.

1. Фаза генерации сборочных скриптов (проектов). За эту фазу отвечает (или можно запустить) пункт меню `Build -> Run qmake`. Либо, если билд-скрипты еще не разу не создавались, то эта фаза запускается автоматически. Соответственно, если у вас уже есть билд-директория, то при изменении `.pro`/`.pri` файлов, вы должны сами вызывать `Build -> Run qmake`.
2. Фаза сборки проектов. Это либо `Build All` (инкрементальная сборка), либо `Rebuild All`.

Для автоматической генерации билд-скриптов можно сделать [такой хак](http://blog.mgsxx.com/?p=2166):

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += after_build firsthook
firsthook.target = first
firsthook.depends = after_build
after_build.depends = all
after_build.CONFIG = phony
after_build.commands = $(DEL_FILE) $(MAKEFILE)
```

Т.е. после каждой сборки будет удаляться билд-скрипт, и Qt Creator будет сам запускать `qmake` при каждом `Build All`.

Также, посмотрите [хороший гайд по qmake](http://blog.mgsxx.com/?page_id=1294).

**Update**

Если есть какие-то цели (target) выполняемые после сборки всего, то их надо добавить в зависимости `after_build.depend`

```
after_build.depend = all  <список всех целей выполняемых после сборки>
```

чтобы цель `after_build` была самой последней выполняемой командой.

Comment: стоит иметь в виду, что при таком хаке все объектники будут пересобираться заново при каждой сборке...

Comment: Проверил - объектники **не пересобираются**, но линковка таргета (.dll или .exe) запускается каждый раз.

Comment: нуда, был не прав... так и должно быть... что-то меня понесло... от Makefile'а же, действительно, по умолчанию цели не зависят...